# Algebraic numbers in the interval $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

A number $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is said to be algebraic if it is the root of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$. Define $A:[0,1]\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ as 
$$A(x)=1 \text { if } x \text{ is algebraic, } A(x)=0\text{ if } x \text{ is not algebraic, }$$

What is the value of $\int_{0}^{1} A(x)dx$ ?

Comment: The set of algebraic numbers is countable...

Comment: It depends on whether you are making a Riemann integral or a Lebesgue integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of all algebraic numbers is countable .use it to deduce the value=0